# Where can you find the list of all the methods supported by strings in python?

Tags: python

Where can you find the list of all the methods supported by strings in python

Comment: Related: [Finding what methods a Python object has](/q/34439/4518341)

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum and that you are expected to make some attempt to solve problems yourself before asking here. I can literally copy and paste `Where can you find the list of all the methods supported by strings in python?` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Where+can+you+find+the+list+of+all+the+methods+supported+by+strings+in+python%3F) and get useful results. If you have ever previously heard the word `documentation`, that is also extremely useful for Internet searches.

Answer (score 3):

In the official documentation: [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)